# SVN issue in spring source tool when starting the tomcat

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tortoisesvn, tomcat7

i get the following exception when i try to run the tomcat server in spring source tool.
i have installed `svn 1.7 in system but svn 1.6.x in sts`

I am not able to fix this issue. could some body help me.

```
delete --force D:/works/dailyship/target/m2e-wtp/web-resources
    D         D:/works/dailyship/target/m2e-wtp/web-resources/META-INF/maven/src.main/java/pom.properties
    D         D:/works/dailyship/target/m2e-wtp/web-resources/META-INF/maven/src.main/java/pom.xml
    D         D:/works/dailyship/target/m2e-wtp/web-resources/META-INF/maven/src.main/java
    D         D:/works/dailyship/target/m2e-wtp/web-resources/META-INF/maven/src.main
    D         D:/works/dailyship/target/m2e-wtp/web-resources/META-INF/maven
    D         D:/works/dailyship/target/m2e-wtp/web-resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
    Unsupported working copy format
svn: The path 'D:\works\dailyship' appears to be part of a Subversion 1.7 or greater
working copy.  Please upgrade your Subversion client to use this
working copy.

    Unsupported working copy format
svn: The path 'D:\works\dailyship' appears to be part of a Subversion 1.7 or greater
working copy.  Please upgrade your Subversion client to use this
working copy.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't (can't) mix two version of SVN even if then are in two different place but working with same code. Upgrade STS plugin version to 1.7.

Comment: @Anto: Right now I dont have STS on my machine. May be you can google it (How to do it or google whatever error you are getting)